# $_SESSION not passing to javascript

Tags: php, session, javaagents

This is probably a simple issue but I would appreciate any help
I have loaded a $_SESSION variable from my MVC model , its a multidimensional area of latitude and longitude points in a map. here where I loaded this from

```
         for($i=0; $i<count($markets['results']); $i++) {
        .
        .
     $marketinfo["lat"][$i] = floatval($lat);
             $marketinfo["long"][$i] = floatval($lon);
             };
          $_SESSION['MARKETLOCATION']['LAT'] = $marketinfo["lat"];
          $_SESSION['MARKETLOCATION']['LONG'] = $marketinfo["long"];
```

Then down in the view section I am calling a _template for header with this code

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
            function createmap(LatLong) {
            var firstpass = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < $LatLong.length; i++) {
                   var  lat = $LatLong['LAT'][i];
                   var  lng = $LatLong['LONG'][i];
                    if (firstpass === true){
                            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),{
                                zoom: 10,
                                center: new google.maps.LatLng($lat[0]+','+$lng[0]),
                                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                            });
                            firstpass = false;
                    }
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng($lat[i]+','+$lng[i]),
                        map: map
                    });

                    }
            window.onload=function(){("createmap($_SESSION['MARKETLOCATION']");};
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='Mapbox' id = 'map-canvas' ></div>
```

Problem is the map is not displaying at all. I know that my API key is correct because I tested it before I created this code. So I think it probibaly has to do with Passing the session variable 
Again any insight would be appreciated

Comment: Check your window.onload function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript and php are two different languages. You need to output your variable from php but you cannot just echo it as `$_SESSION['MARKETLOCATION']` is an array.

You should do something like:

```
var session_variable = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['MARKETLOCATION']); ?>;
// now you might have to do some processing on session_variable like parsing it...
// for an example:
var session_object = JSON.parse(session_variable);
window.onload=function(){ createmap(session_object); };
```

Comment: tried this and it showing the correct array information however it does not seem to parse correctly once in the function create map... here the output when I changed it to your suggestion

Comment: @Jan You need to do a `console.log(LatLong);` in your function. You will probably find it is not an array but an object with 2 properties.

Comment: Thanks jeroen you were correct session_variable was indeed an object (with 2 arrays in it session_variable
Object {LAT: Array[19], LONG: Array[19]}
) as this were the lat long for the markers on the map I just reference them from the param passed to the function.  in my code (ie  position: new google.maps.LatLng(session_variable.LAT[i],session_variable.LONG[i])) thanks again consider this solved

Answer (score 0):

Fix you code:

```
window.onload=function(){("createmap(<?php echo $_SESSION['MARKETLOCATION'] ?>");};
```

Comment: Please explain to the OP what they did wrong and how your code will fix the issue.  This will help their understanding.